# Disable Specific Date and all the past dates in Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, calendar

i want to disable specific dates and all the past dates in Razor pages calendar. I have database table to store the specific dates, i want to fetch from there and disable the dates in the razor pages calendar.

```
<input asp-for="ManageBooking.BookingDate" class="form-control" min="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
```

this is what i will be doing for disabling all the past dates, but i want to disbale certain dates that will be reading from Database.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,
Teena John

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker](https://getdatepicker.com/4/)? It will be convenient.

First, install the corresponding Nuget package:

```
Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker
Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS
```

Then, refer to the corresponding js file and css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, you can disable specified dates and past dates via the `disabledDates` attribute and the `minDate` attribute:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker5'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
                    disabledDates: [
                        "01/17/2023",
                        "01/18/2023",
                        "01/19/2023"
                    ],
                    minDate: "01/16/2023"
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Test Result:

[image]

For more details, you can refer to [this link](https://getdatepicker.com/4/#enableddisabled-dates).